# Get Google Business Notifications from push Pub/Sub

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api

I'm trying to be notified when a new review is added on my Google Business Profile.

[According to the documentation](https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/notification-setup), I have setup the notification but I got nothing when a new review is added.

First of all, I have created a Pub/Sub Topic `projects/my-project/topics/business-profile-notifications`.

Then, I have created a Push subscription `projects/my-project/subscriptions/business-profile-notifications-push` attached to the previous created Topic. I have also defined an endpoint: `https://my-endpoint/webhook`. This endpoint is listening `POST` requests

Finally, I have added the service account `mybusiness-api-pubsub@system.gserviceaccount.com` into IAM with Pub/Sub admin role.

On the code side, I'm using NPM `googleapis` client in a TypeScript Node.js server.

I'm updating the account settings to setup the notifications:

```js
const { data }: GaxiosResponse<mybusinessnotifications_v1.Schema$NotificationSetting> = await google.mybusinessnotifications({
    version: 'v1',
    auth,
  }).accounts.updateNotificationSetting({
    name: `accounts/${params.accountID}/notificationSetting`,
    updateMask: 'notification_types',
    requestBody: {
      name: `accounts/${params.accountID}/notificationSetting`,
      pubsubTopic: 'projects/my-project/topics/business-profile-notifications',
      notificationTypes: [
        'NEW_REVIEW',
        'UPDATED_REVIEW',
      ],
    },
  });
```

At this point, nothing happens when a new review is added.

When I'm sending a POST request on my endpoint via curl command `curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -i "https://my-endpoint/webhook"`, the request is successfully catched.

In the other hand, when I'm getting notifications settings from the configured account, I have the notifications types but not any subscribed topic:

```js
const { data }: GaxiosResponse<mybusinessnotifications_v1.Schema$NotificationSetting> = await google.mybusinessnotifications({
    version: 'v1',
    auth,
  }).accounts.getNotificationSetting({
    name: `accounts/${accountID}/notificationSetting`,
    fields: 'pubsubTopic,notificationTypes',
  });
```

Response:

```js
{
  "notificationTypes": [
    "NEW_REVIEW",
    "UPDATED_REVIEW"
  ]
}
```

What I forgot to do ?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by myself

In [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/notifications/rest/v1/accounts/updateNotificationSetting) of `updateNotificationSetting` method, is it stated that "The only editable field is notificationSetting" about the `updateMask` field. But it's wrong. I had to add `pubsubTopic` as value.

Finally, the parameter values of this method are:

```js
const opts = {
  name: `accounts/${params.accountID}/notificationSetting`,
  updateMask: 'notificationTypes,pubsubTopic',
  requestBody: {
    name: `accounts/${params.accountID}/notificationSetting`,
    pubsubTopic: params.pubsubTopic,
    notificationTypes: params.notificationTypes,
  },
};

const { data }: GaxiosResponse<mybusinessnotifications_v1.Schema$NotificationSetting> = await google.mybusinessnotifications({
  version: 'v1',
  auth,
}).accounts.updateNotificationSetting(opts);
```